# Logical operation to fill new colum in dataframe with character values

Tags: r, dataframe, logical-operators

I have a data frame on broadband data for various countries (take AT_df for example). The columns "ofWithTV" and "ofWithFT" are of type character and indicate whether each case (broadband offer) comes with a bundled TV access or Fixed Telephony access, with (or without any) both of them.

```
ofWithTV    ofWithFT  
no          no
no          no
no          no
yes         no
yes         no
no          no
no          yes
no          yes
no          yes
no          yes
yes         yes
yes         yes
```

I want to create a new column "ofProduct" where those cases shall be called "Singleplay" where both events are "no", "TV Doubleplay" where the events are "yes"; "no", "FT Doubleplay" where the events are "no"; "yes" and "Tripleplay" where both events are "yes". Something like this:

```
ofWithTV    ofWithFT   ofProduct
no          no         Singleplay
no          no         Singleplay
no          no         Singleplay
yes         no         TV Doubleplay 
yes         no         TV Doubleplay
no          no         Singleplay
no          yes        FT Doubleplay
no          yes        FT Doubleplay
no          yes        FT Doubleplay
no          yes        FT Doubleplay
yes         yes        Tripleplay
yes         yes        Tripleplay
```

For this, I need a logical operation to assign the new values "Singelplay, Doubleplay,..." without deleting/overwriting existing data. I already searched for something similar but cannot find/understand how those operations actually work..

I am new to this community and also new to R (first post here). Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `case_when` from the [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr).

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(ofProduct = case_when(
    ofWithTV %in% "no" & ofWithFT %in% "no"   ~ "Singleplay",
    ofWithTV %in% "yes" & ofWithFT %in% "no"  ~ "TV Doubleplay",
    ofWithTV %in% "no" & ofWithFT %in% "yes"  ~ "FT Doubleplay",
    ofWithTV %in% "yes" & ofWithFT %in% "yes" ~ "Tripleplay"
  ))
dat2
#    ofWithTV ofWithFT     ofProduct
# 1        no       no    Singleplay
# 2        no       no    Singleplay
# 3        no       no    Singleplay
# 4       yes       no TV Doubleplay
# 5       yes       no TV Doubleplay
# 6        no       no    Singleplay
# 7        no      yes FT Doubleplay
# 8        no      yes FT Doubleplay
# 9        no      yes FT Doubleplay
# 10       no      yes FT Doubleplay
# 11      yes      yes    Tripleplay
# 12      yes      yes    Tripleplay
```

Or we can create a look-up table first and then join the table to the original data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

look_up <- tribble(
  ~ofWithTV, ~ofWithFT, ~ofProduct,
  "no"     , "no"     , "Singleplay",
  "yes"    , "no"     , "TV Doubleplay",
  "no"     , "yes"    , "FT Doubleplay",
  "yes"    , "yes"    , "Tripleplay"
)

dat3 <- dat %>%
  left_join(look_up, by = c('ofWithTV', "ofWithFT"))
dat3
#    ofWithTV ofWithFT     ofProduct
# 1        no       no    Singleplay
# 2        no       no    Singleplay
# 3        no       no    Singleplay
# 4       yes       no TV Doubleplay
# 5       yes       no TV Doubleplay
# 6        no       no    Singleplay
# 7        no      yes FT Doubleplay
# 8        no      yes FT Doubleplay
# 9        no      yes FT Doubleplay
# 10       no      yes FT Doubleplay
# 11      yes      yes    Tripleplay
# 12      yes      yes    Tripleplay
```

**DATA**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ofWithTV    ofWithFT  
no          no
no          no
no          no
yes         no
yes         no
no          no
no          yes
no          yes
no          yes
no          yes
yes         yes
yes         yes",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked perfectly